# for loop behavior inconsistent

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writting a script that should start several nodes of a distributed erlang application (on the same maschine though). here is a stripped down example of the code:

```
start_extra_node() {
    echo "starting node $1"
    port=$((14195+$1))
    mystartcommand -p $port -n node$1 --daemonize
    res=$?
    if [ $res -ne 0 ]; then 
        echo "ERROR: could not start extra VM node $1"
        exit
    fi
    return $res
}

make_run() {
    echo " "
    echo "----------------------------------------------"
    echo "making run with $3 nodes"
    start=$2
    end=$(($3-1))
    echo "$start $end"
    for i in $(seq -s " " $start $end); do
        echo "start node $i"
        start_extra_node $i
    done
}

case $# in
    0)
        usage;;
    1)
        echo "starting node that runs the function st:$1 ..."
        start_api_node $1;;
    2)
        echo "running evaluation on 1 to $2 nodes"
        for i in `seq -s " " 1 $2`; do
            echo "make_run $1 1 $i"
            make_run $1 1 $i
        done
        ;;
    esac
```

The script is called with 2 parameters: first one is unimportant here. The 2nd parameter is the maximum number of nodes. The script should run a function on 1 to $2 nodes.

Suppose I start the script with `bash myscript foo 3`:

Depending on the presence of `mystartcommand -p $port -n node$1 --deamonize` in `start_extra_node` the for loop in `make_run` behaves differently.
If I leave it in `port=$((14195+$1))` fails since $1 evaluates to `1 2`. If I comment out `mystart...` the arithmetic expression does not fail since $1 evaluates to `1` and then `2` as expected.

Here is an example output with `mystartcommand...`:

```
>bash myscript foo 3
...[snip]
making run with 3 nodes
1 2
start node 1 2
starting node 1 2
eval_mr.sh: Zeile 17: 14195+1 2: Syntaxerror in expression.
```

and one where `mystart...` is commented out:

```
>bash myscript foo 3
...[snip]
making run with 3 nodes
1 2
start node 1
starting node 1
start node 2
starting node 2
```

I have no idea on how to further debug this. I will be thankfull for any lead.

*edit* deamonize to daemonize

Comment: BTW, are you sure it's really `--deamonize` and not `--daemonize`?

Comment: Try adding `set -xv` at the top of the script to debug.

Comment: And try to become accustomed to using variables this way: `make_run "$1" 1 "$i"`, `start_extra_node "$i"` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to imagine that this really comes from leaving out that `mystartcommand`. It must have something to do with the `$IFS` stuff.

You could try to replace

```
for i in $(seq -s " " $start $end); do
```

with

```
for ((i=$start; i<=$end; $i++)); do
```

in order to have a real loop.

Comment: yeah that works allright. but I'm still baffled why the loop semantic would be different when something seemingly unrelated changes.